# c# How to use a TableAdapter from a xsd dataset

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I added a TableAdapter to an xsd dataset. I wonder how to use it. When I type "Dataset1."  It seems I cannot access the class by code, this way I cannot do anything with it.
Thanks for any answer

Comment: Have you tried Google, or even searching this site?

Comment: I am searching this site, but it is useless if code completion does not give me a reference to the class I cannot do anything with it

Answer (score 0):

I found I have to add `using TestReports.DataSet1TableAdapters;`
Now I can access the class